# Accessing $post in function scope

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, templates

I have a situation where I need to loop through posts outside of The Loop using foreach.

The following loop works fine, however, when I migrate practically the same code into a function (to keep the code DRY), issues occur: the template code repeats certain $post elements (such as thumbnails, titles etc) while returning expecting information for other $post elements (such as the excerpt).

There is clearly something I am missing or misunderstanding here about how to work with $post within functions or in the template code, however, I cannot figure this one out.

Any clarification would be great.

*Original Code:*

```php
$posts = get_field( 'featured_projects', 'user_'.$post->post_author );

if( $posts ){
        $current_index = 0;
        $grid_columns = 3;

    foreach ($posts as $post){

        if( 0 === ( $current_index  ) % $grid_columns ){
            echo '<div class="row archive-grid" data-equalizer>';
        }

        setup_postdata($post);

        get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'custom-grid' );

        if( 0 === ( $current_index + 1 ) % $grid_columns
            ||  ( $current_index + 1 ) ===  3 ){
                    echo '</div>';
            }

        $current_index++;

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

*Refactored as Function:*

```php
function get_grid(){
$posts = get_field( 'featured_projects', 'user_'.get_post()->post_author );

if( $posts ){
    $current_index = 0;
    $grid_columns = 3;

  foreach ($posts as $post){

    if( 0 === ( $current_index  ) % $grid_columns ){
      echo '<div class="row archive-grid" data-equalizer>';
    }

    setup_postdata($post);

    get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'custom-grid' );

    if( 0 === ( $current_index + 1 ) % $grid_columns
      ||  ( $current_index + 1 ) ===  3 ){
          echo '</div>';
      }

    $current_index++;

  }
  wp_reset_postdata();

}
}
```

*Loop-custom-grid Template code*

```php
<div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>

 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?> 
 role="article">

<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
  <section class="archive-grid featured-image" itemprop="articleBody" style="background-image: url('<?php
    echo esc_url( get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'medium') );
  ?>');">
  </section>
<?php endif; ?>

<header class="article-header">
  <h3 class="title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
  <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'byline' ); ?>
</header>

<section class="entry-content" itemprop="articleBody">
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other functions do not receive the `$post` you expect when the loop is inside your function. The `$post` variable only "exists" inside that function.

One simple way to solve it would be to just put your `$post` variable in the global scope:

```
function get_grid(){
    global $post;
    $posts = get_field( 'featured_projects', 'user_'.get_post()->post_author );
    /* all the other code that works fine outside
       a function should work fine inside too now */
}
```